ArcGIS API result encoding
I'm trying to scrape a table of results from ArcGIS but can't figure out what encoding the files are being returned in.
Where can I find documentation on this?
To access the API endpoint:
curl --output test.csv -X GET 'https://services.arcgis.com/ciPnsNFi1JLWVjva/ArcGIS/rest/services/CE_NwkHcv_StructureHCV_Prod/FeatureServer/1/query?f=csv&cacheHint=true&resultOffset=10&resultRecordCount=50&where=1%3D1&orderByFields=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects'

This is my first time working with ArcGIS.

That service is not creating csv for you you need to request:
JSON,
GeoJSON,
HTML, or
PBF
To get GeoJSON
using:
https://services.arcgis.com/ciPnsNFi1JLWVjva/ArcGIS/rest/services/CE_NwkHcv_StructureHCV_Prod/FeatureServer/0/query
result:
> {   "type": "FeatureCollection",   "properties": {
>     "exceededTransferLimit": true   },   "features": [
>     {
>       "type": "Feature",
>       "geometry": {
>         "type": "Point",
>         "coordinates": [-73.902081, 40.876491]
>       },
>       "properties": {
>         "DIV_NAME": "BRONX"
>       }
>     },
>     {
>       "type": "Feature",
>       "geometry": {
>         "type": "Point",
>         "coordinates": [-73.927987, 40.806226]
>       },
>       "properties": {
>         "DIV_NAME": "BRONX"
>       }
>     },
>     {
>       "type": "Feature",
>       "geometry": {
>         "type": "Point",
>         "coordinates": [-73.927328, 40.807147]
>       },
>       "properties": {
>         "DIV_NAME": "BRONX"

https://services.arcgis.com/ciPnsNFi1JLWVjva/ArcGIS/rest/services/CE_NwkHcv_StructureHCV_Prod/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&resultType=none&distance=0.0&units=esriSRUnit_Meter&relationParam=&returnGeodetic=false&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&featureEncoding=esriDefault&multipatchOption=xyFootprint&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&defaultSR=&datumTransformation=&applyVCSProjection=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnUniqueIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&returnQueryGeometry=false&returnDistinctValues=false&cacheHint=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&having=&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&returnExceededLimitFeatures=true&quantizationParameters=&sqlFormat=none&f=pgeojson&token=

(You can load this up in QGIS and export to the attributes to .csv)
